# Created a merge from A to B but in the history in SourceTree, I can see it was from B to A

Tags: merge, commit

Hello,

I use Git and Github.

I use a branch "A" for a first project and I use a branch "B" created from "A" for a second project.

Weekly, I merge "A" into "B" to keep "B" up-to-date.
I am sure I merge "A" into "B" but when I check the history on SourceTree, I can read the message "Merge branch B into A", how is it possible?

Thanks